# Selecting the most recent value of a column from a Postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, window-functions

I've got some data in a Postgres table that looks like:

```
Name | Date      | Balance
--------------------------
A    |2020-01-01 |    1
B    |2020-01-01 |    0
B    |2020-01-02 |    2
A    |2020-01-03 |    5
```

(note that `A` is missing a value for `2020-01-02` and `B` for `2020-01-03`)

I'd like to fill in the missing date with it's most recent value for that name. In other words, I'd like

```
Name | Date      | Balance
--------------------------
A    |2020-01-01 |    1
B    |2020-01-01 |    0
A    |2020-01-02 |    1 <--- filled in with previous balance
B    |2020-01-02 |    2
A    |2020-01-03 |    5
B    |2020-01-03 |    2 <--- filled in with previous balance
```

Note that in reality, several dates may be missing in a row, in which case the most recent one for that name should always be selected.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking `generate_series()` and window functions:

```
select 
    n.name, 
    s.date, 
    coalesce(t.balance, lag(balance) over(partition by n.name order by s.date) balance
from (select generate_series(min(date), max(date), interval '1 day') date from mytable) s
cross join (select distinct name from mytable) n
left join mytable t on t.name = n.name and t.date = s.date
order by n.name, s.date
```

If you may have several missing dates in a row, then a little more logic is needed - this basically emulates `lag()` with the `ignore nulls` option:

```
select
    name,
    date,
    coalesce(balance, first_value(balance) over(partition by name, grp)) balance
from (
    select 
        n.name, 
        s.date, 
        t.balance,
        sum( (t.balance is not null)::int ) over(partition by n.name order by s.date) grp
    from (select generate_series(min(date), max(date), interval '1 day') date from mytable) s
    cross join (select distinct name from mytable) n
    left join mytable t on t.name = n.name and t.date = s.date
) t
order by name, date
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! One last question, what if I wanted to be able to filter above a certain date, but still have the coelesced balance include the most recent value (even if the value is before the given date)?

Comment: @Octodone: you would need to turn the query to a subquery, and do the date filtering in the outer query.